# SyliusTaxonomiesBundle : taxon declaraed as not a object in model Taxonomy

Tags: php, symfony, taxonomy, sylius

I downloaded and installed SyliusTaxonomiesBundle, and when I want to create a taxonomy, I get the following problem:

FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function setName() on a non-object in /home/jeremy/web/vendor/sylius/taxonomies-bundle/Sylius/Bundle/TaxonomiesBundle/Model/Taxonomy.php line 72

the problem at this level,

```
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->root->setName($name);

    return $this;
}
```

As if root is not an object TaxonInterface.

you can see the model files: Taxonomy and Taxon in this link :
https://github.com/pjedrzejewski/SyliusTaxonomiesBundle/tree/v0.9.0/Model

Thank you very much !!

Comment: actually, what's the solution then? Thank you very much !!

Comment: Your `root` must be an object with public `setName` method

Comment: In Taxonomy.php, it's declared as an object actually :

Comment: /**
    * Root taxon.
    *
    * @var TaxonInterface
    */
    protected $root;     due to annotation

Comment: and setName is declared in Taxon.php as a public function !!